# How to perform K means clustering for residue pairs?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset in the form of a csv file which consists of three columns: R1, R2 and Frequency which corresponds to Residue1, Residue2 and the Frequency between them respectively. I want to perform a clustering on this data. But I am unware as to how exactlyt should I proceed. Because when i perform the clustering between R1 and R2 i just get a symmetric plot [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymYq4.png). What I would really like to do is to first assign pair number to each pair. For example, if this is my data:
R1    R2    Score
1      2     0.5
1      3     0.4
1      9     0.3
2      10    0.1
2      15    0.2

Then the table would become:
Pair    Score
Pair1    0.5
Pair2    0.4
Pair3    0.3
Pair4    0.1
Pair5    0.2

And then I would like to perform the clustering where those pairs that have an score of above 0.8 have one colour, those that have score between 0.3 and 0.8 have another colour and below 0.3 have another colour.

I have tried it in two ways. One where i perform the K means clustering but don't get the desired outcome:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    import numpy as np  

    csv_file_path = 'contact.csv'
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

    pairs = data[['R1', 'R2']].values.tolist()
    mi_values = data['Score'].values.tolist()

    num_clusters = 3  
    mi_values_array = np.array(mi_values).reshape(-1, 1)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, random_state=0).fit(mi_values_array)

    data['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_

    colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k']  # Add more colors if needed
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

    for cluster_id in range(num_clusters):
        cluster_residues = data[data['cluster'] == cluster_id][['R1', 'R2']].values.tolist()
        x = [pair[0] for pair in cluster_residues]
        y = [pair[1] for pair in cluster_residues]
        plt.scatter(x, y, label=f'Cluster {cluster_id + 1}', c=colors[cluster_id])

    plt.xlabel('Residue 1')
    plt.ylabel('Residue 2')
    plt.title('Residue Pairs Clustering')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

I have also used pyviz to just visualise the network based on the desired cutoff to see how the residues are connected to each other[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwMUf.png). I know that pyviz is not a clustering technique, I only did this to just visualise the network. I tried the following:

```
    import networkx as nx
    from pyvis.network import Network
    import pandas as pd
    from IPython.core.display import Image
    from PIL import Image
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    filtered_df = data[data['Score'] > 0]

    # Extract unique residue pairs from the filtered DataFrame
    residue_pairs = set(zip(filtered_df['R1'], filtered_df['R2']))

    # Create an empty undirected graph
    G = nx.Graph()

    # Add the residue pairs as nodes to the graph
    G.add_nodes_from(residue_pairs)

    # Create an interactive network visualization
    net = Network(notebook=True)

    # Create a dictionary for node colors
    node_colors = {}

    # Add nodes and edges to the interactive network
    for node in G.nodes():
        res1_label = node[0]
        res2_label = node[1]
        mi_score = 0.0  # Initialize mi_score to a default value
    
        # Find the corresponding row in the filtered DataFrame
        # and get the MI score
        if (res1_label, res2_label) in zip(filtered_df['R1'], filtered_df['R2']):
            mi_score = filtered_df[(filtered_df['R1'] == res1_label) & (filtered_df['R2'] ==     res2_label)]['Score'].values[0]
    
        # Define color based on the MI score conditions
        if mi_score >= 0.8:
            node_colors[node] = 'red'
        elif 0.3 <= mi_score < 0.8:
            node_colors[node] = 'blue'
        else:
            node_colors[node] = 'green'
    
        # Add nodes with color to the interactive network
        net.add_node(res1_label, label=f'Res1: {res1_label}', color=node_colors[node])
        net.add_node(res2_label, label=f'Res2: {res2_label}', color=node_colors[node])
        net.add_edge(res1_label, res2_label)

    # Show the interactive graph
    net.show_buttons(filter_=['nodes', 'edges', 'physics'])
    net.show('interactive_graph.html')
```

I would like to perform the clustering based on this type of dataset. I would also like to know whether clustering can be perform don such a dataset and if yes then whether I should go with K means or any other clustering technique. Any help would be appreciated.